# How to hyperlink a variable string as an email address in href mailto with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, email, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to add an email address into the body of my email and hyperlink it dynamically, since the variable I'm using is a string and could change for each email according to the spreadsheet I'm using.

Here's the basics of my code:

```vb
Dim SpFirstName As String
Dim SpLastName As String
Dim StrBody2 As String
Dim SpEmail As String

SpFirstName = cell.Offset(0, 3)
SpLastName = cell.Offset(0, 4)

SpEmail = SpFirstName & "." & SpLastName & "@abc.com"

StrBody2 = "<a href = 'mailto:SpEmail'>" & SpEmail & "</a>"
```

I have two columns in the spreadsheet that give the person's first and last name and the critera (where the offset is based off) is a company name.

SpEmail returns the value I want (John.Doe@abc.com or Jane.Doe@abc.com) and it displays the email address in the body of the email when it populates as a hyperlink, but when you click on the hyperlink, it opens a new message TO: spemail. Not the email address I've created through the string.

Is it possible to get the hyperlink to link to the email address that might show up?

Answer (score 1):

```
"<a href = 'mailto:" & SpEmail & "'>" & SpEmail & "</a>"
```

I figured it out myself... I had tried this before, but missed a double quote somewhere I'm pretty sure.